# how can i make a private method in to its own class for using over and over

Tags: java, android, class, private, public

i have this method which is in my main activity, but i want to use it in other classes, how can i write it into its own class so it can be called when ever?
i have tried to make a java class called isCallable with a constructor called the same but im getting lost with what to put in the constructor
thanks for any help

```
 private boolean isCallable(Intent intent) {

    if (intent == null) {
        return false;
    }
    List<ResolveInfo> list = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent,
            PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
    return list.size() > 0;

}
```

Comment: Create a class, e.g. Util.java. Now copy above method in that class and make it static.

Now from any activity you can call it by given method call....
Util.isCallable(intent).  You don't even need to create object of class Util.

Comment: so instead of private it becomes static?

Comment: Yeah, remove private.

Comment: brill thanks @Devanshu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step #1: Create a Java class named `HarropUtils`.

Step #2: Implement the following `static` method on `HarropUtils`

```
static boolean isCallable(Context ctxt, Intent intent) {

    if (intent == null) {
        return false;
    }
    List<ResolveInfo> list = ctxt.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent,
            PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
    return list.size() > 0;

}
```

Step #3: Call `HarropUtils.isCallble()` from wherever you need it, passing in a `Context` (e.g., an `Activity`) and the `Intent` to test.